# Re-assign CTRL+left arrow to move to beginning of line

Tags: keyboard

I'm trying to make a custom shortcut through the ubuntu settings.  I'm used to CTRL+left arrow taking you to the beginning of your current line, not just to the previous word.  I assume I'm just not using the right command line for this command shortcut.  I've tried CTRL+V in the terminal to get the key output of the home key (which does take you to the beginning of a line) and using that as the command, but it was not the proper command. I've tried "beginning-of-line" but that doesn't work either.  I feel this is easy to get done but I don't have the knowledge.  So the home key does what I want, but I'd rather attribute that function to the CTRL+left arrow combination.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for all applications as a global hotkey, or just in the terminal? If it's as a global hotkey, which desktop environment are you using (or which version of Ubuntu)?

Comment: Not necessarily a solution to your specific question but... I use Ctrl+a and Ctrl+e which are already mapped. You might look at what those are doing, and copy the functionality to the arrow key combination.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.2 and I'm looking to use it as a global hotkey.  Ctrl+a only works in the terminal as everywhere else it's select all.